# Add milliseconds to datetime obj

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am using `PHP 7.1.8` and I am converting a timestamp to a datetime obj:

```
$t = 1546464670412;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$result = date ('c', (int) round ($t / 1000));
$msec = (int) $t % 1000;
$ts = str_replace ('+00:00', sprintf (".%03dZ", $msec), $result);
$f = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", strtotime($ts));
var_dump($f);

// Output
/*
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2019-01-02 21:31:10"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(1)
  public $timezone =>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
*/
```

The timestamp is correctly converted to H:m:s, however I would like to also add milliseconds.

Any suggestions which DateTime format I have to use?

Thank you in advance or your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen anyone use so many conflicting date functions in so many wrong ways all at once. Pick one. Specifically the DateTime interface.

```
$t = 1546464670412;
$f = DateTime::createFromFormat("U.u", $t/1000);
var_dump($f);
```

`$t/1000` results in the float `1546464670.412` which is implicitly cast to string and parsed according to the [specified format](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters). You do not need to set the default timezone as timestamps are all implicitly UTC as they have no mechanism with which to convey a timezone.

Result:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-01-02 21:31:10.412000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```